# Why is Url.EmailConfirmationLink returning null

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I am stuck on something.

In the new project generated code, there is this code which creates a URL which can be inserted into an email.

```
public static string EmailConfirmationLink(this IUrlHelper urlHelper, string userId, string code, string scheme)
    {
        return urlHelper.Page(
            "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
            pageHandler: null,
            values: new { userId, code },
            protocol: scheme);
    }
```

I am using it, but it always returns null.

Yet in another place in code, which creates a URL for resetting password, it does work.  The code is identical, yet one works, and other doesn't.  So it means there is something wrong with the parameters.  But I see no difference in the parameters.

These parameters work:

scheme: `"https"`

userId: `"47520958-d9be-4f50-add3-b56bbe607db1"`

code: `"CfDJ8BDMTyrHOg9JlayOwfP2DlxkCwozoq0o5TmyKtmg1KC/+PPXvp/HwMC9LP+S1+NDYaMk9lVNRYHBAjfBWnfqJ9msre2t02eQSVQwrM0tx1bXd3cfbTFC0WYEkvSNWo8dkLIc3izlPsQJ+Xi1aq8D/skgQ6WoKI9Tsk8y53UdYq47W4iK6dhORZiU3h1L5dXWPJh2Cj6xfEy7u2hVhu4rjWYxyQz1ic7BfiJTkLMtHVot"`

These do not:

UserId: `"9e006f58-3869-4b99-aeb7-0cd7b4567013"`

code: `"CfDJ8BDMTyrHOg9JlayOwfP2DlwMwzc+RVxw6s8CXV/Uw3FYidocTDd0tk/VFUS3SCUMcWfttRTGtQL7cDbqwg9HX6r58xMqpyfqbMVFIiJD5/s37roSKU9FAAanbMJjgvAFiYiO3rXEntVfPcGimW5LTqeajaQrVOFAyAlNbqNqGbKJ9nmTo7hbFQ/zwk4TWbjt/nfK00V18C2+7bqcGJdX8ZS15K4kID68VU6nAAf5j5YpDoVp8hbVXZWF7Vi/S0yhNw=="`

scheme: `"https"`

Comment: Does `/Account/ConfirmEmail` exist?

Comment: @IanKemp, Yes, it does exist. As another test, I used the other method with the bad parameters, and it also returns null. So the route seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that if the page is under an area, the area must be included like this:

```
 var callbackUrl = Url.Page(
    "/Account/ConfirmEmail",
    pageHandler: null,
    values: new { area = "Identity", userId = user.Id, code = code },
    protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

This was answered here: https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/8280